# How to remove all files without deleting the directory?

Tags: command-line, bash, directory, rm

I have a sample `dir` as follows:

```
/path/to/dir/
- f1.txt
- f2.txt
- f3.txt
```

I want to clear or remove all the files under `/path/to/dir` without actually deleting the directory `/path/to/dir` itself.

How to do it?

Currently, I am just using the `rm -rf /path/to/dir` command to remove the directory and the creating the directory again using `mkdir /path/to/dir`. But this command deletes the directory also.

Answer (score 7):

Use wildcard (`*`)

```
rm /path/to/dir/*
```

Will remove all file under `/path/to/dir` directory.

Comment: Or, `rm -r /path/to/dir/*` if there are directories under `/path/to/dir/`

Answer (score 4):

Remove all files and directories in directory `dir/` including .dot files.

```
$ find /path/to/dir/ -mindepth 1 -delete
```

Comment: In order to delete the files but keep the sub directories, you could add `-type f` after the depth option. Also you could add `-maxdepth 1` if you want to keep the content of the sub directories.